# Logback: use Java main class name as log filename

Tags: logback

I have several executable classes and I would like to automatically set the log filename to the name of the Java class being executed.

I know I could do this programmatically, probably using Reflection and [`MDC`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/mdc.html), but isn't there an easier way to achieve this by configuring `logback.xml`?

This seems a rather basic need to me, so I am surprised I could not find documentation about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on a JVM that supports it you can use this property

```
<file>${sun.java.command}.log</file>
```

Otherwise you need to set a similar system property in all your `main` methods that logback can use.

Comment: Thank you. This property seems to be not supported when launching through Eclipse on Windows, but it works when launching on Ubuntu through Maven. I get a string such as `org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=mypackage.MyMainClass` and with some cleaning I should be able to isolate the class name.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind specifying the application name twice in your command line, you can specify a java system variable to be the application name of your choice, and reference that system variable in your logback configuration file.

Eg. Your command...

```
java -DAPPNAME="Class1" Class1
```

... passes the value "Class1" as a java system variable which logback picks up, and you can reuse like this...

```
<appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
    <file>${APPNAME}.log</file>
    <encoder>
        <pattern>%msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
</appender>
```

Answer (score -1):

As you mentioned, you can easily achieve this by doing:
`Logger loggerA = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass().getSimpleName());`

I think it's pretty comfortable setup, so Logback didn't bother with allowing explicit xml configuration for that.

So, you can collect all your logs from `this.getClass()` that appear in Class1 and Class2 to one logger with package name `com.company` (Class1 and Class2 share this namespace):

```
    <appender name="MY_STUFF" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/my_log.server_%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <logger name="com.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="MY_STUFF" />
    </logger>
```

Comment: `LoggerFactory.getLogger` simply returns a logger named as the string passed, but it does not impact the log filename for `FileAppender`s. And even if I manage to set the log filename equivalent to the logger name, that's not what I want: every class would log to a separate file, while I want that all classes log to a file named as the main class being executed.

Comment: You correct, it does not impact the log filename for FileAppender. Just use namespace that will include in all the loggers you create in `LoggerFactory.getLogger` (for example com.company.yourclass) in your `logback.xml`: 

   `<logger name="com.company" level="INFO" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="APPENDER" />
    </logger>` Did I understood correctly?

Comment: Let me try to explain what I need with an example. If I execute `Class1.java`, _all_ classed called during the execution should log to *class1.log*. If tomorrow I create and run a new executable class named `Class2.java`, everything within that execution should go into *class2.log*, without me having to change any setting. Makes sense now?

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I don't really see the meaning for it- just catch all the Classes with the shared namespace they have in the `<logger>` itself, you will need the configure the *real* logger in any case, in the `logback.xml` file: `<logger name="com.company"> <appender-ref ref="APPENDER" /> </logger>` //`com.company` is the shared namespace.

Comment: @StasS `this.getClass()` is often a common class used by both `Class1` and `Class2`.  How does your example create `class1.log` and `class2.log`?

Comment: @antak it's not, in my example i'm showing how both `this.getClass()` of `Class1` and `Class2` collected to one logger that defined with the shared namespace.

Comment: @StasS `Class1` and `Class2` may be run at the same time.  Using a shared log file means you're introducing a concurrency risk.  This risk may be averted by setting `prudent=true`, however this has its own problems.  Aside from the [performance overhead](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent) of using `prudent=true`, what you can do with the `RollingFileAppender` also becomes [severely limited](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudentWithRolling).